# JSON.parse returning [Object object] Looking to access properties of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, local-storage

So I am trying to do some front end unit testing for my web app. In the view where the user can add a product, I have the following code:

```
 var ProductEntry = {Title: ProductTitle, Description: Description, Hashtags: Hashtags,
            Picture1: Picture1, Picture2: Picture2, Picture3: Picture3, Start: startdate, ETA: 
            ETADate}

        ProductsArray.push(ProductEntry);

        localStorage.setItem("Product", JSON.stringify(ProductsArray));
```

In the view where I am trying to retrieve the Array my jQuery code is:

```
 $("#SearchButton").click(function(){
        var SearchQuery = document.getElementById("SearchField").value; 
        var storageObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Product"));
        alert(storageObject[1].Title);           
    });
```

Above, I am trying to access the property 'Title' of the ProductEntry object. Where am I going wrong? Switching over from C# MVC environment for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that ProductEntry you were trying to create is not a valid JSON.

Try this code:

```
    var ProductEntry = [{Title: 'ProductTitle', Description: 'Description', Hashtags: 'Hashtags',
                Picture1: 'Picture1', Picture2: 'Picture2', Picture3: 'Picture3', Start: 'startdate', ETA: 
                'ETADate'}]

            localStorage.setItem("Product", JSON.stringify(ProductEntry));

 $("#SearchButton").click(function(){
        var SearchQuery = document.getElementById("SearchField").value; 
        var storageObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Product"));
        alert(storageObject[0].Title);           
    });
```

Comment: Worked!! Thank you! What makes up a valid JSON? Could you possibly link me to some documentation as I am new to this.

Comment: @AlimCharaniya Ok great, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON that is the official page for JSON, and please accept my answer if t was helpful to you.

Comment: Actually, I see that each object property you passed in JSON is a literal, what if I want to pass vars to each property of an object?